# Flutter resusable methods/widgets

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm working on a flutter project where I need to reuse a function. But below implementation showing me blank output. Please help.

```
_storeCard(String url, String text) {
    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontSize: 15.0,
          fontFamily: "WorkSansSemiBold",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: (20 / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2)),
            children: [
              _storeCard('abcd', 'Processor'),
              _storeCard('abcd', 'Graphic Card'),
              _storeCard('abcd', 'Motherboard'),
            ],
          ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a blank output because you give to childAspectRatio a too big value

Try to remove or change this line:

```
childAspectRatio: (20 / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2)),
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But how to decrease the height of grid

Comment: `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 400` this worked!